# Where to initialize Doctrine's default transaction isolation level in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'd like to set a default transaction isolation level of `READ COMMITTED`, instead of MySQL's default `REPEATABLE READ`, throughout my Symfony application.

Basically, I need to ensure that the following method is called on `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` whenever this class is injected:

```php
$connection->setTransactionIsolation(TransactionIsolationLevel::READ_COMMITTED);
```

What is the correct place to do this in a Symfony application? I though about the `Kernel`, but am not sure how to do this without having to unconditionally instantiate the `Connection`.

Instead, this should only be called *if* and *when* the `Connection` is instantiated by the dependency injection container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a configuration option available to control for transaction isolation at bundle level.

But one could decorate `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory`, and on `createConnection()` set the transaction isolation level before returning the created connection.

```
# services.yaml
    App\YourOwnConnectionFactory:
        decorates: '@doctrine.dbal.connection_factory'
```

```php
class YourOwnConnectionFactory
{
    private ConnectionFactory $decorated;

    public function __construct(ConnectionFactory $decorated) {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function createConnection(array $params, Configuration $config = null, EventManager $eventManager = null, array $mappingTypes = []) {
        $connection = $this->decorated->createConnection($params, $config, $eventManager, $mappingTypes);
        $connection->setTransactionIsolation(TransactionIsolationLevel::READ_COMMITTED);
        return $connection;
    }
}
```

---

You could also change the definition of `doctrine.dbal.connection` to add a call to `setTransactionIsolation()` within a compiler pass. Not sure it would be any better. I guess both methods have its own shortcomings that you'd need to evaluate according to your own circumstances:

```php
class FooPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
            $container
                ->getDefinition('doctrine.dbal.default_connection')
                ->addMethodCall(
                    'setTransactionIsolation',
                    [TransactionIsolationLevel::READ_COMMITTED]
                );

    }
}
```

Yet another option is to use add a configurator function to the compiler pass:

```php
class FooPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container
            ->getDefinition('doctrine.dbal.default_connection')
            ->setConfigurator([self::class, 'setTransactionIsolationLevel']);
    }

    public static function setTransactionIsolationLevel(Connection $connection) : void
    {
        $connection->setTransactionIsolation(TransactionIsolationLevel::READ_COMMITTED);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I'm a bit reluctant to decorate a class that does not implement an interface, though; it's much more fragile to upstream changes. I mean, sure there won't be breaking API changes before the next major version, but static analysis won't be able to understand the problem where it'll happen. Isn't there a way to just *intercept* the `Connection` right after it's been created through dependency injection, and before it's returned to the caller? Can't the `Container` be configured to do this?

Comment: Well, I guess you could change the definition of the default connection service to add the desired method call. Not really sure it's any better, but maybe you'll find it more to your taste. See edit.

Comment: Hmm I don't really like it either, indeed. I was more expecting something that would accept a callback function to configure the freshly constructed object, something like: `->addCallback(function(Connection $connection) { $connection->setTransactionIsolation(...); });`, but maybe there is no such thing in Symfony DI.

Comment: The above is basically the same. `addMethodCall` adds a method call to a freshly configured service. The answer solves the question statement, but if there were additional constraints those should be mentioned in the question. It's starting to look like what you are looking for it's more like a specialized kind of service definition, although I'm not sure I understand exactly how would apply differently than the above. It's a pity you do not find it useful or helpful.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being picky, I appreciate your answers and am just really making sure that we haven't overlooked anything. Sure, your second solution (compiler pass) is very close to what I had in mind, but this `addMethodCall` is where the shoe pinches: it does the same thing, but is not static analysis-friendly. The same thing with a callback would be exactly what I'm after.

Comment: You were definitely on the right track with the compiler pass. I discovered that an alternative is to use `setConfigurator()`, you may want to add to your answer: [example](https://gist.github.com/BenMorel/14f91b4dbd21bf805c0a8c27c413a67b). Unfortunately this method does not accept a Closure, it only accepts a callable in the form of an array of class and method name.

Comment: I took the liberty to update your anwer with the configurator option. I guess we've investigated all possible options now. Thanks for your time!

Comment: all of this will break `doctrine:database:create` command, because it sends `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL ...` to a non existend Database.
So I prefer the Decorator and surround the `setTransactionIsolation()` call with try/catch